# Using the pumping lemma for a specific language

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Please help me with the following question:

> Define the language LONGERB to be the set of strings over $\{a,b\}$ where the longest substring containing only $b$’s is strictly longer than the longest substring containing only $a$’s (e.g. $aabaabaaabbbba$ is in LONGERB because the longest substring containing only $b$’s has length 4 while the longest substring containing only $a$’s has length 3, while $ab$ is not in LONGERB). Let $n$ be the integer from the pumping lemma. How many of the following strings can be used in a pumping lemma proof that LONGERB is not regular?
>
> (i) $abab^{n+1}$ (ii) $a^nb^{2n}$ (iii) $a^{10}b^{10}$ (iv) $a^nb^n$

The answer that has been given in the book is 3 (Options 1,2, and 4). But my doubt is, that the 4th option doesn't belong to the given language as there is an equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s in this option. So, according to me the correct answer should be 2 (Options 1 and 2 only).

Please give a proper reason for each of the four options, why it can or cannot be used to prove that the given language is not regular.

Comment: Only (i) and (ii) are actually in the language. But for pumping they should have the property that *any* regular pumping does lead outside the language. Only (ii) satisfies that condition, if we have the usual condition that pumping must occur within the first n symbols of the string.

Comment: So, you are saying that only 2nd option is correct? @Hendrik Jan

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1: the word is in the language and it is of length $\geq n$, yet there is no guarantee that pumping it yields a contradiction. That is, the word can be used in the pumping lemma, **but its not a good choice for proving non-regularity**. Indeed, if $\text{LONGERB}$ is regular, then we know that there is a partition of $abab^{n+1}$ to three words, $xyz = abab^{n+1}$, where $|xy| \leq n$, $|y|> 0$, and $xy^iz\in \text{LONGERB}$ for every $i\geq 0$. Thus, if for example $y = ba$, then $xy^iz$ is indeed in $\text{LONGERB}$ for every $i\geq 0$ -  so we cannot reach a contradiction to the assumption that $\text{LONGERB}$ is regular.
- Option 2: the word is in the language and it is of length $\geq n$. Clearly it is good for pumping in the sense that it can be pumped for some $i$ so that $xy^i z \notin \text{LONGERB}$ - this is an easy exercise and the details are left to you.
- Option 3: the word is of constant length that does not depend on the pumping constant $n$, so there is no guarantee that it is of length $\geq n$, so the pumping lemma says nothing about this word. Thus, we cannot use it to apply the pumping lemma on any language with a pumping constant $n$.
- Option 4: you're right, the word cannot be used when applying the pumping lemma directly on the language $\text{LONGERB}$. However, it can be used to prove the non-regularity of $\text{LONGERB}$ indirectly by applying the pumping lemma on the language $\overline{\text{LONGERB}}$ which is the language of the words over $\{a, b\}$ where the longest substring containing only $b$’s is *equal or shorter* than the longest substring containing only $a$’s. Indeed,  assume by contradiction that $\overline{\text{LONGERB}}$ is regular. If you consider the word $w = a^n b^n$, it is longer that $n$ and it is in the language $\overline{\text{LONGERB}}$. Then, there is a partition $xyz = a^nb^n$, where $|xy| \leq n$, $|y|> 0$, and $xy^iz\in \overline{\text{LONGERB}}$ for every $i\geq 0$. If you pump with $i = 0$, you get a contradiction. (BTW, I implicitly assumed that both a language and its complement have the same pumping constant $n$. This assumption is okay. Can you tell why?)

Comment: Thank you so much sir :)